Inserting with cx_Oracle suddenly takes forever, But in sql developer everything is normal time
I have the below code which used to work up until today, basically I am passing bunch of lists to be inserted into database using python.the previous lines before below code  takes columns from a pd dataframe and then switches all to a list.
then in the following code it inserts them into database.
but now it takes long time with no results still. I made few adjustments today but nothing make the code not work.  Sometimes I see a tag on the buttom saying "except cx_oracle.databaseerror " but it is still running the code.


    # Execute the query
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    
    # Commit the transaction
    connection.commit()

    print("Data inserted successfully.")

except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as exc:
    error, = exc.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", error.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", error.message)


You left a session opened with an uncommitted transaction ?

@p3consulting   Thinking about it I think I did yes, I forgot to put connection.commit() at a point

It sounds like you left changes uncommitted in SQL Developer - either commit or rollback in your session in that client before trying to run this code.

I did it in pycharm not sql developer tho

A side comment: don't forget to schedule your upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was released under the new name python-oracledb a couple of years ago, see the release announcement.

cx_oracle is old/deprecated - replaced with python-oracledb


I have the below code which used to work up until today, basically I am passing bunch of lists to be inserted into database using python.the previous lines before below code takes columns from a pd dataframe and then switches all to a list. then in the following code it inserts them into database. but now it takes long time with no results still. I made few adjustments today but nothing make the code not work.

The row that you are trying to modify has probably been UPDATEd by as earlier session (probably SQL Developer) but that first session has not issued a COMMIT or ROLLBACK so the row is locked and the second session is waiting for the lock to be released.
Try running the Python code and if the code is waiting "forever" then go to whichever application has the first session open (maybe SQL Developer or another Python instance that is still running) and run the COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) command in that first session and see if the Python code then suddenly completes. If it does then it was waiting for the lock to be released on the row.
If you don't know what session has locked the row then you can try closing everything else and, when the connection is closed, the data will implicitly ROLLBACK any changes. If this still doesn't work then you can try terminating all the inactive sessions connected to the database (ask your colleagues first just so you don't kill something that someone is actively using).
